# getStaticPaths and getStaticProps are failing during next build

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have this Next.js Application with a [slug] for Static Site Generation, all is good and works fine on my localhost and when I try to deploy it the following error shows:

`“Unhandled error during request: TypeError: Cannot read property ‘title’ of undefined”.`

And when I try to run next build command on my localhost the following error shows:

`Error occurred prerendering page "/jobs/[slug]". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`

Here is the code for your information

```
export default function Listing({ job }) {

    const router = useRouter()

    if (!router.isFallback && !job?.slug) {
        return <ErrorPage statusCode={404} />
    }

    return (
        <div >
            <div >
                <div >
                <div >
                <div >
                <div>
                    <h1>
                    <span>Job Center</span>
                    <span >{job.title}</span>
                    <p>We are looking for interested candidates for the following position. </p>
                    </h1>
                    <div>
                            <div >
                                <span>Position: </span><span>{job.title}</span> //and multiple fields like this
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
    
}
 
export async function getStaticProps({ params, preview = false }) {
    const data = await getJobAndMoreJobs(params.slug, preview)
    return {
        props: {
            preview,
            job: data.job
        },
    }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const jobs = await getAllJobsWithSlug()
    return {
        paths: jobs.map(({ slug }) => ({
            params: { slug },
        })),
        fallback: true,
    }
}
```

Furthermore I have another API file which pulls the data from a fetchAPI from a GraphQL Schema and Query. Here is the attached code below:

```
async function fetchAPI(query, { variables, preview } = {}) {

    const res = await fetch(process.env.JOBS_PROJECT_API, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${
              preview
                ? process.env.JOBS_DEV_AUTH_TOKEN
                : process.env.JOBS_PROD_AUTH_TOKEN
            }`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query,
            variables,
        }),
    })
    
    const json = await res.json()
  
    if (json.errors) {
        console.log(process.env.NEXT_EXAMPLE_CMS_GCMS_PROJECT_ID)
        console.error(json.errors)
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch API')
    }
  
    return json.data
    
}
  
export async function getPreviewPostBySlug(slug) {

    const data = await fetchAPI(
        `
        query PostBySlug($slug: String!, $stage: Stage!) {
            post(where: {slug: $slug}, stage: $stage) {
              slug
            }
        }`,
        {
            preview: true,
            variables: {
                stage: 'DRAFT',
                slug,
            },
        }
    )
    
    return data.job
    
}
  
export async function getJobAndMoreJobs(slug, preview) {

    const data = await fetchAPI(
        `
        query JobBySlug($slug: String!, $stage: Stage!) {
            job(stage: $stage, where: {slug: $slug}) {
                title
                section
                slug
                vacancies
                rank
                classification
                placeOfWork
                basicSalary
                serviceAllowance
                allowances {
                    name
                    percent
                    requirement
                }
                responsibilities
                requirement
                documents
                expirationDate
                expectedInterviewDate
                gazetteLink
                a2Form {
                    url
                }
            }
            moreJobs: jobs(orderBy: publishedAt_DESC, first: 2, where: {slug_not_in: [$slug]}) {
                title
                slug
                title
                section
                slug
                vacancies
                rank
                classification
                placeOfWork
                basicSalary
                serviceAllowance
                expirationDate
                expectedInterviewDate
                }
            }      
        `,
        {
            preview,
            variables: {
                stage: preview ? 'DRAFT' : 'PUBLISHED',
                slug,
            },
        }
    )
    
    return data
    
}
```

Any help regarding this is much appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: Can you check the content of the response from the fetch call? Seems like the request fails during the production build and maybe your error handling process is not right (since it works in localhost you have no way to tell if handle error scenarios correctly when they happen).

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this same issue and finally figured it out via the [Next Documentation on `getStaticPaths` with `fallback: true`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fallback-true):

> If `fallback` is `true`, then the behavior of `getStaticProps` changes:
>
> - The paths that have not been generated at build time will not result in a 404 page. Instead, Next.js will serve a “fallback” version of the page on the first request to such a path (see “Fallback pages” below for details). Note: this "fallback" version will not be served for crawlers like Google and instead will render the path in blocking mode.
>
> ...
>
> In the “fallback” version of a page: The page’s props will be empty.

This means that Next will render a fallback version of this page at build time as if you'd returned `props: {}` from `getStaticProps`. Because there's no `job` prop passed, adding `job.title` to your JSX is causing the error you're seeing.

Assuming you'd like to keep `fallback: true` enabled, there are two ways to resolve this:

#### 1. Gracefully handle empty page props

Ensure that the page successfully renders even if passed an empty props object. In this case, you could use default/fallback values:

```js
export default function Listing({ job = { title: "Fallback Title" } }) {
    // ...
    return (
        <div>
            <span>{job?.title}</span>
            <span>{job?.title || "Fallback Title"}</span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

#### 2. `router.isFallback`

If a page is being rendered as a fallback, Next's `router` will have a property `isFallback` set to `true`. You can bail out entirely from rendering by checking for this:

```js
export default function Listing({ job }) {

    const router = useRouter()

    if (router.isFallback) return null;

    // ...rest of component
}
```